# DAE Jacobian matrix StiffnessSwitching alternative

Tags: matrix

I am trying to do the Jacobian Matrix of my DAE system. Below you can find a simplified example:

```
pars = {k1d -> 1, k1r -> 0.1, keq -> 5, eps -> 10.^(-5)}
DAEEqs = {x'[t] == -k1d*x[t] + k1r*(y[t])^2,
      (y[t])^2 == keq*x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == Sqrt[keq*1] } /. pars
SetAttributes[StiffnessJacobianMonitor, HoldFirst];
StiffnessJacobianMonitor[i_, method_NDSolve`StiffnessSwitching] := 
  If[SameQ[method["ActiveMethodPosition"], 2] && i < 5, 
   If[MatrixQ[#], Sow[#];
      i = i + 1] &@method["Jacobian"]];
i = 0;
jacdata = 
  Reap[sol = 
      NDSolve[DAEEqs, {x, y}, {t, 0, 30}, 
       Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
       "MethodMonitor" :> (StiffnessJacobianMonitor[i, 
           NDSolve`Self];)];][[-1, 1]];
```

Here I have an error:

NDSolve::nodae: The method NDSolve`StiffnessSwitching is not currently implemented to solve differential-algebraic equations. Use Method -> Automatic instead.

Do you have any idea on how to do this? My model is much more complex than this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Inês

Comment: Could you give some more context for your code? Are you trying to adapt existing code?

Comment: No, I just want to have the jacobian matrix for a DAE system. The example above with the stiffness switching works well for a ODE system and that's why I decided to put. Thanks,

Comment: Can you differentiate the algebraic equations?

Comment: Hi Michael, I have a lot of equations so I was trying to find another way to do this.